# incorrect result of fasttext model

Tags: pyspark, sentiment-analysis, fasttext

I created a fasttext model to do comments sentiments analysis , I used a train_File with 51% positive comments, 47% negative and 2% neutral.
When I want to test with some given sentences always results are divided between: 0.49 .. positive, 0.47 .. negative, 0.02 neutral, even if I type a single negative word.
I have the following code :

```
import fasttext


model = fasttext.train_supervised(TRAIN_FILE, lr=0.1, dim=20, epoch=20, word_ngrams=1 , loss='softmax')

model.save_model(MODEL_FILE)
model = fasttext.load_model(MODEL_FILE)

pred = model.predict(['bad'], k =3)
print(pred)
```

I get always a result around 0,4.. positif , 0,4... negatif , 0.0.. neutral :

```
([['__label__négatif', '__label__positif', '__label__neutre']], array([[0.49168783, 0.47954634, 0.02879585]]))
```

Can someone tell me where the mistake lies

Comment: How many rows does the train set contains?
If your dataset is small, maybe you can use pretrained word vectors as a starting point...

Comment: The train set contains 1019 rows :  2 columns : text and label

Comment: Please post 4 or 5 rows of your train set...

Comment: It will be better if you employ pre-trained word embeddings at this stage. You can choose from either count-based GloVe or prediction-based word2vec algorithm. In case you want to train corpus-specific word embeddings, you need to identify a resource that gives you millions (or at least 100,000s) of pre-labeled positive, negative and neutral instances. Train word embeddings from this large corpus and employ it on your task.